# How to execute two task with context switching in C++ with Boost

Tags: c++, mysql, boost

this is my first question here, so I hope I will describe my problem after the rules and hope you will understand it.

I try to programming some extras in MySQL. For that I need to synchronised the tasks of the queries.

At the begin both task will wait for execution. One task is the producer (the master) and the other task will be only the consumer (the slave).

Each query will go into the method `execQuery` when I want to switch the tasks. About the `QueueElement e` they know each other.

If it have a slave itself is the master and if it have a master itself is a slave in the other cases the slave or master object is `0`. 
So with a third thread I start the master task. When it finished the first calculation it go into the `execQuery`method and starts the execution of the slave and wait there. The slave start and read the data of the master (not here in the code) and go also into the `execQuery`method and start the master again and wait and so on. If all data are calculated and read it ends. 
Normally it works like that. But sometimes I have the following problem:

The master get into the `execQuery` method and make `slave->cond.notify_all();` So the slave task starts and executed all stuff and go into the `execQuery` method and executed `master->cond.notify_all();` before the master task executed the next line: `e->cond.wait(lock);` So the slave wake up nothing and both threads are sleeping then. Because the slave task is too fast here.

What I need is a solution here how I can arrange that that the task will wake up the other task and start to wait than before the other task start to executed. Is there a solution?

```
void QueryQueue::execQuery(JOIN* toSearch) {
if (QueryExport::isSystemQuery(toSearch)) {
    return;
}
QueueElement* e = getQueryElement(toSearch);
BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "Enter execMultiQuery with id: " << e->join->thd->query_id;
if (e) {
    if (e->slave) {
        QueueElement* slave = e->slave;
        BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "Wait for Query " << e->join->thd->query_id << " and start " << slave->join->thd->query_id << " (Slave) ";



        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(e->mut);

        slave->cond.notify_all();
        e->cond.wait(lock);
        BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "Wake up Query " << e->join->thd->query_id << " (Master) ";

    }
    if (e->master) {
        QueueElement* master = e->master;
        BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "Wait for Query " << e->join->thd->query_id << " and start " << master->join->thd->query_id << " (Master) ";


        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(e->mut);

        master->cond.notify_all();            
        e->cond.wait(lock);
        BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "Wake up Query " << e->join->thd->query_id << " (Slave) ";
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem. So I want to share the solution with you all. Probably it helped someone else.

I need a new variable to hold the status and the working thread (the slave) needs to hold the mutex of the master while it works. So in the slave part there must be a new lock part.

I'm found a forum there was a similar problem: http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Deadlock-issue-with-boost-condition-td2554763.html

That problem is easier to understand from that form that my. But it is the same problem.

```
void QueryQueue::execQuery(JOIN* toSearch) {
if (QueryExport::isSystemQuery(toSearch)) {
    return;
}
QueueElement* e = getQueryElement(toSearch);
BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "Enter execMultiQuery with id: " << e->join->thd->query_id;
if (e) {
    if (e->slave) {
        QueueElement* slave = e->slave;
        BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "Wait for Query " << e->join->thd->query_id << " and start " << slave->join->thd->query_id << " (Slave) ";

        slave->cond.notify_all();


        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(e->mut);


        e->cond.wait(lock);
        while(!e->worker_thread_finished ) e->cond.wait(lock);
        e->worker_thread_finished = false;   
        BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "Wake up Query " << e->join->thd->query_id << " (Master) ";

    }
    if (e->master) {
        QueueElement* master = e->master;
        BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "Wait for Query " << e->join->thd->query_id << " and start " << master->join->thd->query_id << " (Master) ";

        {
            boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(e->master->mut,boost::try_to_lock);
            if (!lock.owns_lock()) {
                BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(warning) << "Can't lock the Query with ID " << e->master->join->thd->query_id << " (Master) ";
            }
            master->worker_thread_finished = true;
            master->cond.notify_one();
        }

        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(e->mut);

        e->cond.wait(lock);
        BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "Wake up Query " << e->join->thd->query_id << " (Slave) ";
    }
}

}
```